# Run Liquibase without license warning using Community Edition

Tags: gradle, liquibase, gradle-plugin

We use Community Edition of Liquibase in our project. When running Liquibase via gradle tasks we see this warning:

> WARNING: License service not loaded, cannot determine Liquibase Pro
> license status...

Is it possible to disable this warning or to define that only free features can be used, so that this message disappears?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to disable this warning. If you would like to propose that change, best thing to do is drop a github issue requesting it. https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues  (or a PR if you are able). Thanks much!